# Including tip amount in an Order

Tags: square, square-connect

I'm having trouble using the Square Connect API. I need to add the amount for tips but I don't see a place where I can do that in the Transaction Charge endpoint neither in the Order CreateOrder one.

The only place that tip is mentioned is in the Tender object, property `tip_money`, but we can't send a Tender when creating a Transaction or Order.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge

Have anyone ever implemented this using the Square Connect v2 API? We're developing an app using a completely customized UI so we can't use webviews from Square or anything.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot add a tip through Square APIs. The only way to add a tip is when taking a payment through the Square POS application, if you have tipping enabled. When you do take such payments, they will show up in the `Tender` object (which is a part of a `Transaction`) as you found.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that changed since you posted your reply? Is there a work around for that (assume pure API, no Square POS)

Answer (score 0):

Square has now added the ability to add a tip through the payments API.

See: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment#request__property-tip_money